# Keras fails while processing word embedings

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

```
word_embed = keras.layers.Embedding(len(vocab), 101)
em = word_embed(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(10, 48)))

print(em.shape) 
# (10, 48, 101)    
# 10 sentences in bacth, 48 words in sentence(with padding), 101 - embedding dimension...

lstm = K.layers.LSTMCell(101)
lstm_layer = keras.layers.RNN(lstm)hidden_states = lstm_layer(em) 

# TypeError: Expected Operation, Variable, or Tensor, got False
```

Who can help, why an error occured? Hidden states of lstm cells expected...

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you passing an `lstm` layer to a `RNN` layer and why are you using `LSTMCell` isntead of `LSTM`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the word Embedding to your LSTM layer in your model like below.

Here I'm considering binary classification example, having embedding dimension as 101, max number of words in a sentence 48.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding,Dense,LSTM  

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(vocab), 101, input_length=48))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
## Fit the model
model.fit(data, np.array(labels), validation_split=0.4, epochs=3)
```